# How to fix the query built by union in knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js, pg

I am using knex with pg for getting some data from my DB. 
The query that I am trying to build by knex is:

```
select "fixtime" from "positions" order by "fixtime" desc limit(1) 
union 
select "fixtime" from "positions" order by "fixtime" limit (1)
```

but, knex return the following query when I used 'union'. And I get the error when I am trying to get the result.

`console.log(db.select('fixtime').from('positions').orderBy('fixtime').limit(1).union([db.select('fixtime').from('positions').orderBy('fixtime','desc').limit(1)]).toSQL())`

this is the result of console:

```
select "fixtime" from "positions" 
union 
select "fixtime" from "positions" order by "fixtime" desc limit ? order by "fixtime" asc limit ?
```

`db.select('fixtime').from('positions').orderBy('fixtime').limit(1).union([db.select('fixtime').from('positions').orderBy('fixtime','desc').limit(1)]).then(arr => console.log)`

this is the error I got: 
Unhandled rejection error: syntax error at or near "order"

When I used a single query I can get the result.
How can I fix this query with knex or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible with `Knex` in the way you are trying it to do. There is an [issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/913) that describes something similar.

But... You can cheat your way to the result with `Postgres` by using two [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
const sql = db
  .with('first', qb => {
    qb.select('fixtime')
      .from('tc_positions')
      .orderBy('fixtime', 'asc')
      .limit(1);
  })
  .with('last', qb => {
    qb.select('fixtime')
      .from('tc_positions')
      .orderBy('fixtime', 'desc')
      .limit(1);
  })
  .select('*')
  .from('first')
  .union(function() {
    this.select('*').from('last');
  })
  .toSQL();

console.log(sql);
```

this yields:

```
WITH "first" AS (
    SELECT
        "fixtime"
    FROM
        "tc_positions"
    ORDER BY
        "fixtime" ASC
    LIMIT ?
),
"last" AS (
    SELECT
        "fixtime"
    FROM
        "tc_positions"
    ORDER BY
        "fixtime" DESC
    LIMIT ?
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "first"
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "last"
```